# How many Postgres connections is normal for a 4 CPU & 32 GB machine (db.m5.2xlarge)?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

We have about 100 concurrent connections open and I'm wondering if that is suitable or we should be working to reduce that number.  CPU is about 80% utilized.

I'm happy to extrapolate from other machine sizes if you have numbers for larger or smaller VMs.

Comment: If you are looking for 'opinions', you might get a better response at: https://www.reddit.com/r/aws

Comment: An open and **idle** connection does not consume any CPU. So apparently all your connections are doing something. If that is what your application requires, then there isn't much you can do about apart from getting a faster server

Comment: There is no direct relation between 100 concurrent (active?) connections and 80% CPU utilization. A single connection could cause this 80%. What proces is causing this 80% ? And is 80% something good or something bad? A CPU is made to work for you. However I have reduced CPU utilization by speeding up queries creating useful indexes. So, what is causing this 80% ?